# Unable to specify Pythonversion to create Glue job using Lambda Python 3.7 boto3 create_job

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-glue

Unable to specify Pythonversion in Lambda function written in Python 3.7 boto3 create_job using below code

Seems to be some bug in boto3 post recent Spark & Python support release from AWS Glue

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/aws-glue-now-supports-ability-to-run-etl-jobs-apache-spark-243-with-python-3/

As per documentation Pythonversion is mandatory value to specify

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_job

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
client=boto3.client('glue')
response = client.create_job(
Name='JOB_NAME',
Role='ROLE',
Command={
'Name': 'glueetl or pythonshell',
'ScriptLocation': 'S3 LOCATION',
'PythonVersion': 'PYTHON VERSION'
}
)
```

However when created using CLI, it worked but Python version drop down is not working in Glue job

```
aws glue create-job --name "###" --region "###" --role "###" --command Name="glueetl",ScriptLocation="###",PythonVersion="3"
```